# How to get UNITY native notification for gogle chrome?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, notification, libnotify

I have tried the below link

[Activate Chrome native notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465727/activate-chrome-native-notifications)

But there is no such files and folders in above said answers when I installed the google Chrome recently to version 38

How can I get native ubuntu unity notification even for my google chrome?