# Move Chrome notifications or use system notification

Tags: unity, google-chrome, notification, notify-osd

### The problem

I have the Chrome notifications popping up in the lower left corner of my main screen. This is quite annoying, 'cause the cursor of my terminal windows are right there, and they cover completly the command line.

I'm on **Ubuntu 14.04** and **Chrome 42**

I've already tried:

- making my secondary (on the **right**) screen as primary: it still display notifications on the lower left angle of my **left** monitor
- [Activate Chrome native notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465727/activate-chrome-native-notifications)

  - **Libnotify Notifications** in Chrome doesn't work, even with the modifications proposed by the accepted answer
  - **Linux Native Notification** is incompatible, needs Unity plugin (what's that???)
  - **Chromify-OSD** requires NPAPI, that I can't install, it's deprecated

### Question

What can I try? I will accept any of those solutions:

- redirect the notifications to Unity
- move them in an other angle of my screen
- move to an other monitor (I'm using Chrome on the secondary monitor)

### Also...

I also found this on Chromium FAQs:

> Q. Why don't Chromium notifications use the D-BUS-based notifications
>   system (aka libnotify / notification-daemon)?
>
> A1. HTML5 notifications can contain arbitrary HTML, which is not
>   supported by the notification protocol.  (This is the same reason we
>   don't use Growl on OS X.)
>
> A2. Chromium's notifications include a button that brings up an
>   options menu, which is also not supported by the notification
>   protocol.
>
> A3. The glitzy Ubuntu notifications daemon, by design, does not allow
>   the user to interact with notifications at all, which doesn't work
>   when the notification HTML includes clickable links.
>
> A4. It would be nice to extend the protocol to allow Chromium to
>   integrate.  Any takers?

Comment: There is a [bug opened](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=301848) in chromium bug database dated from 2013 and not much activity there

Answer (score 3):

So here's the problem. Like you mentioned, [**NPAPI**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) is on [its way out](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) and Webkit applications are going to make heavy use of their own in-built notification system instead of respecting the one provided by a desktop environment [1]. Unless someone comes up with a way with intercepting the notification requests for the browser and have it to speak at a local daemon that can in turn speak with `notify-osd`; we're out of luck.

Expanding on this, KDE allows for button manipulation in its notification service whereas Ubuntu does not. If they've unified this one action as a generic feature, it might be even more feasible to implement the above. But alas.

[1]: More likely, they want to make it as rich as possible but without worrying too much about cross platform support.

Comment: The Libnotify Notifications Chrome Extension had a daemon that did that, but it doesn't work anymore. It was in my question...

Comment: The daemon you seem to refer to in your question is from the content on the Chrome Developer's page that refers to the notification daemon of the system, _not_ the one provided by `chrome-notify-osd`.

Comment: What's `chrome-notify-osd`? What are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, that was quick typing, I meant just `notify-osd`.

Comment: Ah right. But the daemon provided by the extension should redirect the notification to the `notify-ost` one... Or did I understood that wrong?

Comment: I assumed (and remember possibly incorrectly) that the daemon was something installed outside of Chromium; having the extension work as a bridge.

Comment: It workED. It doesn't work anymore, and I don't have any tool to debug the situation...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-14-04-lts/configurable-notify-osd)?

## Step 1: install patched libnotify

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
pkill notify-osd
```

## Step2: Install config utility

- [32-bit version](https://launchpad.net/~amandeepgrewal/+archive/notifyosdconfig/+files/notifyosdconfig_0.3%2B22%2B201312291016~ubuntu13.10.1_i386.deb)
- [64-bit version](https://launchpad.net/~amandeepgrewal/+archive/notifyosdconfig/+files/notifyosdconfig_0.3%2B22%2B201312291016~ubuntu13.10.1_amd64.deb)

Comment: This patched version is to modify the system notifications. I want to change Chrome's, or alternatively to redirect them to system's. This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than waiting for Chrome to move to system notifications, I decided a temporary hack was in order.  This looks for the popop and moves it. I run it
once a minute from cron.  This is, of course, *nix only.

https://github.com/tonyaiuto/settings/tree/master/move_chrome_notify

The basic idea is
- enumerate all children of the root window (xwininfo)
- look for the one at a specific position from the bottom right corner
- move (and resize) it with xdotool

YMMV: The default X position to move to is almost certainly wrong for everyone but me.