# How to make chrome notification show as Ubuntu's 18.04 gnome native notification?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, google-chrome, notification, notification-area

**Update [Aug 28 2019]**:
Recently, I noticed that web notifications "as native" are working but disappearing without being consumed. If I'm fast enough to click them while appearing, they send me to the correct tab/webapp. If a few seconds pass, without doing anything,the notification disappears.

**Original question**:

I'm trying to make chrome notification show as native notifications on Ubuntu 18.04 (which UI is based on Gnome).

I tried enabling [enable-native-notifications](http://chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications), but it didn't work. See screencap below.

I tried searching Q&Aa like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465727/activate-chrome-native-notifications) and [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/google-chrome-dev-lets-enable-native-desktop-notifications), but they discusses old versions of Ubuntu.

**Any idea how to make chrome notifications appear as native ones on Ubuntu 18.04?** Thanks.

* BTW, I understand that there's a bit of a problem regarding synchronization between browser apps vs. native functionality, meaning, had this feature worked, if I would have consumed a message on the browser's app, would it disappear from the native notifications panel?

[image]